# C cipher go wrong

Tags: c, caesar-cipher, edx

I am trying to make a C program which encrypts messages by "rotating" each letter by  positions, wrapping around from Z to A as needed but i am getting wrong results.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
//Checks if the number of arguments are 2
   if (argc != 2)
   return 1;
   int k;
   int n = strlen(argv[1]);
 //Checks if the second arg(cipher) is a non negative number
   for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++ )
   {
       if (!(isdigit(argv[1][i])))
       {
           return 1;
       }
       k = atoi(argv[1]);
       if (k > 26)
       k = k%26;
       if (k < 0)
       return 1;
  }

unsigned int len_max = 128;
unsigned int current_size = 0;

char *pStr = malloc(len_max);
current_size = len_max;

if(pStr != NULL)
{
int c = EOF;
unsigned int i =0;
    //accept user input until hit enter or end of file
while (( c = getchar() ) != '\n' && c != EOF)
{   

    if (isalpha(c))
    {
        if(isupper(c))
        {
            if ((int)c + k > 90)
            c = (char)((int)c + k - 26);
            c = (char)((int)c + k);
        }
        else
        {
            if ((int)c + k > 122)
            c = (char)((int)c + k - 26);
            c = (char)((int)c + k);
        }
    }
    pStr[i++]=(char)c;

    //if i reached maximize size then realloc size
    if(i == current_size)
    {
        current_size = i+len_max;
        pStr = realloc(pStr, current_size);
    }
}

pStr[i] = '\0';

printf("%s\n",pStr);
    //free it 
free(pStr);
pStr = NULL;
return 0;
}
}
```

:) caesar.c exists
:) caesar.c compiles
:) encrypts "a" as "b" using 1 as key

**:( encrypts "barfoo" as "yxocll" using 23 as key
   \ expected output, but not "yxz\n"**

:) encrypts "BARFOO" as "EDUIRR" using 3 as key
:) encrypts "BaRFoo" as "FeVJss" using 4 as key

**:( encrypts "barfoo" as "onesbb" using 65 as key
   \ expected output, but not "onrsoo\n"**

**:( encrypts "world, say hello!" as "iadxp, emk tqxxa!" using 12 as key
   \ expected output, but not "umpxp, qmw tqxxm!\n"**

**:( handles lack of argv[1]
   \ expected output, not an exit code of 1**

Comment: Don't use _magic numbers_! Format your code properly. And **only** cast iff 1) it is really necessary 2) you understand **all** implications and 3) **fully** accept them.

Comment: Yes why cast `c` to `int` when it is (correctly) already `int`? And why cast it to `char` when it isn't?

Comment: You have absolutely right, i have overdo with typecast.Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To shift a single `char` convert the letters 'A'..'Z' and 'a'..'z' to numbers from 0 to 25. Add `k` and calculate the rest of the division by 26:

```
int c;
while ( ( c = getchar() ) != '\n' && c != EOF )
{   
    if ( !isalpha( c ) )
        continue;

    char firstC = isupper( c ) ? 'A' : 'a';
    int num = (c - firstC + k ) % 26;
    pStr[i++] = (char)(num + firstC); 

    if ( i == current_size-1 ) // -1 because of '\0'
    {
        current_size += len_max;
        pStr = realloc( pStr, current_size );
    }
}
pStr[i] = '\0';
```

Comment: Thank very much it is work with simple words but not with spaces.
I will try to fix it by myself in order to understand the your code.Thank you very much for your time

Comment: But if we reach the maximum  size minus one (127) and the next char is  a non alphabetic char (128), with the continue statement we passed the realloc.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ((int)c + k > 90)
    c = (char)((int)c + k - 26);
c = (char)((int)c + k);
```

I've fixed the indentation here. Think about what this section of code will do, and what might be missing.

Comment: Even if it is not related to your actual problem (where you have a good hint now), you might also want to have a look at the cast to "int" for "c" and why it might be needed.

Comment: This section of code does if the ascii number  of the letter plus the key exceed the number of z (or Z) to start from the beginning (rotation).